# Convert this to standard POS

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

Can you please help me converting following to standard POS

```
A(A + C')(A + B)
```

I have done the following so far

```
(A+AC')(A+B+C.C')
(A+AC'+B.B')(A+B+C)(A+B+C')
(A+AC'+B)(A+AC+B')(A+B+C)(A+B+C')
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have updated what I have done so far

Comment: A* (A+C')*(A+B) is equal to A

Comment: but I want to convert it to standard form, shouldn't there be all of the literals?

Comment: @Alyas I think you need all the literals. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant [canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form) by saying 'standard POS', then,

$$A(A + C')(A + B) = (A+BB'+CC')(A+BB'+C)(A+B+CC')$$
$$=(A+B+CC')(A+B'+CC')(A+B+C')(A+B'+C')(A+B+C)(A+B+C')$$
$$=(A+B+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C')(A+B'+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C')(A+B+C)(A+B+C')$$
$$= (A+B+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C)(A+B'+C')$$

But if you meant simplified by 'standard POS', then 
$$A(A + C')(A + B) = A$$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "standard POS" but I have assumed you mean "reduced standard boolean form".If that is the case then the following applies

let
$$
f = A( A + \bar{C} ) ( A + B)
$$
then by multiplying out we get,
$$
f = AAA + AA\bar{C} + AAB + AB\bar{C} \\
f = A + A\bar{C} + AB + AB\bar{C}  \\
f = A(1 + \bar{C} + B + B\bar{C}) \\
f = A
$$

**Extra Information**: The form of equation your original equation is in called the conjunctive normal form (CNF), it is used extensively in the high level synthesis of circuits because of the simplicity of writing computer programs that manipulate the equation in various ways.Your question shows a good easy example of how equations expressed in CNF form can be easily reduced and manipulated.

Comment: The question is not tagged as being homework and the OP has shown he has tried to attempt the question.The minor error in my answer has also been fixed.

Comment: Thnx for reply, that's correct for simplification, but a standard POS is that have all the literals, so answer must have A, B, C included

Comment: Essentially the function depends on just A, whatever you add in the brackets dos not matter so you can have for example f = A(A + B + C) or f = A(A+B)(A+C), they all just reduce to f = A.

Answer (score 0):

If all the variables must be present in the solution, you need

```
A(B + B')(C + C')
```

OK, I misunderstood "standard product of sums".  It appears, from [this page](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/CAL/digital-logic/formsdef/index.html#prodsums), to be an UNREDUCED form, that calls out every active cell of the map.

```
(A + B' + C')(A + B' + C)(A + B + C)(A + B + C')
```

HOWEVER:  If I were to see this problem on a homework assignment, or a test, barring more detail, I'd expect that the professor was looking to see if we knew how to reduce and simplify the expression, and I would respond with:

```
A
```

Comment: OP asked for POS.

Answer (score -2):

`a(a+c')(a+b)=(a+bb'+cc')(a+c'+bb')(a+b+cc')`